# Python3 Unicode

Tags: python

One of the great improvements of Python 3 over Python 2 is being able to work with non-ascii text, but it doesn't seem to be working on the pi :(

On my pc (python 3.4.1) this works as expected, printing 你好 to the console

```
print('你好')
```

but on my pi (python 3.6.1) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    print('\u4f60\u597d')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there some configuration I'm missing?  I don't think it's the terminal setting since the command line `echo "你好"` works.

If it makes any difference, I'm running Arch linux on the pi.

Comment: I can't actually test it, but did you try : `print(u'你好')` ?

Comment: same result - I think the 'u' is ignored in python 3 as all strings are unicode

Comment: If you're running this in a terminal window, is the terminal window set up for unicode?  I get the same or a very similar error running ubuntu on my chromebook if not.

Answer (score 2):

Ah fixed it - just needed to set the [OS locale](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale) to *en-GB.UTF8* and log back in.

Comment: You can also set the preferences for your terminal specifically.  In `xfce4-terminal`, for example, the "Terminal" menu allows you to set it for the current window, or Edit->Preferences if you want it to stick

Comment: thanks, but as this is running headless I had to set the system default locale